# Start activity using intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I have application with multiple activities.
Start activity -> Login activity -> Map activity.
I have intent filter to intercept specific URLs.
My problem is - intent filter is for Map activity. If application is started - OK because application is active and map activity is in use. If application is not active and android have to start my app and then to go Map activity? I have chain of activities. I can bypass Start activity, but not Login activity.

Do I have to put intent filter in start activity and pas data trought activities until reach Map activity? In this case what will happen if application is already started and map activities is initialized?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by bypassing activity?
The intent filter .MAIN is the activity executed first when running your application. If you want to skip an activity when you are passing intent to another activity, just use the `finish();`. Please give some clarity to your question.
Reffer:  http://www.texperia.com/starting-activity-using-intent-on-button-press-android/  for basics.